# Script to check installed software on several PCs

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop, active-directory

I want to run a script that returns me a txt file with the installed software on each computer of my company.
I can do this physically if I execute a PowerShell Script.

```
*Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table –AutoSize > C:\Users\Anon\Documents\Installed.txt*
```

I'm looking for a way to run this script remotely on several PCs. The PCs are in a LAN environment and they are connected to several servers aswell.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-7

Comment: The downside of remote powershell scripting is that it won't work when the pc is turned off. If the computers are domain joined, you can use a powershell script as login script and make it output to a file stored on the DC.

Comment: Ditto on the PC being off bit, but if they have ['Wake On LAN'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=windows+wake+on+lan&form=ANNTH1&refig=75a6c6745b02426798a3b467beff0d85&sp=-1&pq=windows+wake+on+l&sc=8-17&qs=n&sk=&cvid=75a6c6745b02426798a3b467beff0d85) configured, then they can spin up the machine. Well, not all PC's support that. So, do a ping (Test-Connection -ComputerName 'SomeRemoteHostname') to see if the machine is online before trying anything. Even with WOL, you have to monitor for the machine to be up. The other option is to set this as a logon script, to run once, write to a file.